# A way to add DataContext/Resources via Toolbox

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, datacontext

I have a WPF window with two Window resources defined in xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <cs:MyDataProvider endpoint="ep1" x:Key="datactx1"/>
    <cs:MyDataProvider endpoint="ep2" x:Key="datactx2"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Where MyDataProvider is a simple class like:

```
public class MyDataProvider
{
    [...]
}
```

So, my question:

> Is there a way to add MyDataProvider object via drag and drop from
>   the toolbox (or from elsewhere) and automatically add it to Window.Resources?